# how to display local shell-script/s in browser/firefox?

Tags: shell-script, firefox

I have shell-scripts which have html tags which means they were obviously meant to be seen/displayed in a browser as well. So how do I tell firefox to display the shell script instead of trying to download it. The shell-scripts have .sh and .pl at the end respectively.

The first script starts like -

```
 1  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 2    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 3  <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
 4  <head>
```

and ends with -

```
   231  </div> <!-- id=cgit -->
   232  </body>
   233  </html>
```

The second script also shows the same code .

The files are and will be local in nature. Web-based files should always ask as to what to do.

Comment: configure your httpd daemon to text/html

Comment: "_I have shell-scripts which have html tags_" - your example isn't a shell script, it's (the start of) an HTML document

Answer (score 0):

The way data is processed in a browser depends on the MIME type declared by the server. If you want your browser to render it as html, which is most likely a **terrible idea**, you can change the `Content-Type` header the server returns so that it reflects the type of your data, which would be `text/html; charset=utf-8`, and the `Content-Disposition` header to suggest the browser what to do.

You can reffer to this question for a more detailled explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download#20509354

Comment: I want the ability to do it only for local files, not ones directly from the web.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, the best chance you have is a online sites. Find an online sh viewer like [this](https://jumpshare.com/viewer/sh) and load your file there. This way you can have syntax highlighting there.

Answer (score -1):

(Using Firefox 53) In the firefox bar, go to:

```
about:preferences#applications
```

Then Select 'Applications' from the left hand menu. Search for 'sh' to find the content type of 'shell script'. Change the 'Action' for this content Type to 'use other...' and select firefox.

Comment: There isn't, searching for 'sh' does get me opendocument format, but think it would needs probably its own entry.